# Setting Font Color in Input Field Tooltip

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to set the font color in input field tooltip ( using JavaScript),

```
tooltip=fontflag? "True".fontcolor("Red"):  "False".fontcolor("Green");
```

However,I only get the following unwanted text in tooltip,

```
<font color = "Green">False</font>
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: What sort of tooltip? Got a demo?

Comment: I'm officially baffled... the code looks really strange... you mean to say that your Global `String.prototype` has a method called `fontcolor`? - and it uses text from `this` - which is `True` & `False` ? ... does it render `TrueRed` or `FalseGreen` ?